# writing an extension for Safari 5

Tags: web-applications, browser, safari

As of Monday 7th June 2010 Safari (v5) supports Extensions. Some already exist such as the [Gmail Checker](http://lifefrombelow.com/gmail-checker/) & the upcoming [Coda Notes](http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/06/coda-notes-previe/) by Panic.

So my question...

Where would one begin if one intends to develop an application for Safari 5?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the [Safari developer site](http://developer.apple.com/safari/) on Apple?

Comment: i didnt google safari and developer..focussed more on safari + addons/extensions :-(